# Error when initializing Stage

Tags: java, libgdx, initialization, screen, stage

I made a new class that implements Screen, what I've seen from other people's code is that they create a constructor that takes a parameter of Game game. I did not created a constructor, I think that's the reason why I get the error

```
  public class MainMenu implements Screen{
     public MainMenu(Game game){ //I dont know what are these for
            this.game = game;    //<--
        }


 public void show() {
        btnAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("bitters.atlas"));
        skin=new Skin();
        skin.addRegions(btnAtlas);
        stage=new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);// I get the error here when initializing the Stage
    }
 }
```

the error is `"Cannon resolve constructor 'Stage(int,int,boolean)'"`

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `MainMenu` constructor. The reason you are getting the error is that there is no constructor for `Stage` that takes the parameters `(int,int,boolean)`.

Comment: So how do I create a constructor for stage? can you please tell me what the constructor at the top does? with the parameters of Game game thanks

Comment: You don't need to create a constructor for Stage. You need to use one of its existing constructors, which you can find in the libgdx documentation (or your IDE might show them to you if you hover over the word Stage). Your own constructor for MainMenu is currently just grabbing onto a handy reference to your Game instance so you can use it in your logic when needed. You need to read up a bit on the basics of Java, or you are going to have a very hard time making any progress in learning libgdx.

Comment: I think I see what you did. Stage has a constructor that takes a Viewport, but you may have copied someone's example where they declare the new Viewport in that same line, but you omitted the `new ExtendViewport(` part (or whatever type of Viewport it was). That line should be something like `stage=new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true));` Although it's a bad idea to pass the window dimensions into a Viewport constructor, because then your game will be a different size on different screen resolutions.